# my progress dialog remains open in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have made an asynctask for getting some Json response from a webservice.I have used a progress bar when background processing done it displays,and have finished that progress Dialog in onPostExecute method of my asynctask.Thing is that i got successful response as per needed,But myl progress Dialog remains visible after that,Please can any one tell me how to dismiss it.My code is as below:
**main.java**

private class DoFavourite extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // Showing progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProductDetailActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    String favUrl = Const.API_DO_FAVOURITE + "?product_id=" + pid + "&customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(ProductDetailActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "");
    System.out.println(":::::::::my FAVOURITE URL::::::::::::::" + favUrl);
    // Creating service handler class instance
    BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(favUrl, BackendAPIService.GET);

    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
    System.out.println("=============MY RESPONSE==========" + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_STATUS)) {
                if (jsonObj.getString(Const.TAG_STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    if (jsonObj.getString(Const.TAG_FAVOURITE).equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        flag = 1;
                    } else {
                        flag = 2;
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();

}
```

}

Comment: well do log in onPostExecute(Void result) method and check your condition

Comment: what is wrong in condition? all is good na?

Comment: replace if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss(); with just pDialog.dismiss()

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the progress dialog right. You'll notice the IDE shows a neat little warning sign next to your pd.show(...) line.

What you are doing is

Create an (invisible, irrelevant) progress dialog using new ProgressDialog()

Create another progress dialog with the desired text using pd.Show(), without storing a reference to it.

Dismiss the first dialog. The dialog from (2) remains.

If you replace your code with:

```
//pd = new ProgressDialog(this); 

pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Waiting...", "Please wait five seconds...");
```

Comment: can youi please edit my. code ,I am not getting your answer properly